# Displaying the error message in popped up login box

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl

In the backend I am making a model view object and adding the error message:

```
if (visitor.getVisitorId() == 0) {
  mv.addObject("ERROR", "Invalid Username / Password.");
  mv.setViewName("/frontPage.jsp");
  return mv;
}
```

For the front end I'm doing this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty ERROR}">
  <script>
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  </script>
</c:if>
```

When I refresh `frontpage.jsp`, it pops up that myModal box, but I want it to be displayed when that condition is met, which I have written into the `<c:if>`. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I did that using scriptlet tag it was working fine
but I dont know why `<c:if>` is not working in this case

Comment: Add a log or just `system.out.print` in your controller and refresh your page again. Check app container s console (tomcat etc.) via IDE. If you don't see any log then your request probably doesn't pass through your controller. If so, check `@requestmapping` value.